# How do I concisely assign array values based on the index?

Tags: arrays, syntax, pascal

```
Xaxis:array[1..10] of integer;
begin 
Xaxis[1] :=10;
Xaxis[2] :=20;
Xaxis[3] :=30;
Xaxis[4] :=40;
Xaxis[5] :=50;
Xaxis[6] :=60;
Xaxis[7] :=70;
Xaxis[8] :=80;
Xaxis[9] :=90;
Xaxis[10] :=100;
```

is there a simpler and quicker way of declaring values for an array that this in pascal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
for num := 1 to High(Xaxis) do 
begin
  Xaxis[num] := num * 10
end;
```

But first be sure to declare 'num' as an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop. I forget pascal's syntax but something like `Xaxis[index] := index * 10;` inside a loop would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pre-initialise the array by writing

```
const
 Xaxis: array[1..10] of integer = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100);
```

This approach is better when there's no simple arithmetical function to initialise the array. Had you written xaxis[1]:= 5, xaxis[2]:= 14, xaxis[3]:= 29, etc, then loops would not have been suitable.